# Prophet forecasts exceed the capacity

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I built a prophet model that will allow forecasting the annual coverage of 4G mobile network.

```
> data
          ds    y    Expln
1 2012-08-13 59.0  1.00000
2 2013-08-13 59.0 21.79000
3 2014-08-13 59.0 59.10000
4 2015-08-13 65.0 71.00000
5 2016-08-13 65.0 79.26572
6 2017-08-13 67.0 85.57209
7 2018-08-13 79.0 89.87105
8 2019-08-13 82.0 92.98643
9 2020-08-13 97.8 95.98289
> pred_data
           ds     Expln
1  2012-08-13   1.00000
2  2013-08-13  21.79000
3  2014-08-13  59.10000
4  2015-08-13  71.00000
5  2016-08-13  79.26572
6  2017-08-13  85.57209
7  2018-08-13  89.87105
8  2019-08-13  92.98643
9  2020-08-13  95.98289
10 2021-08-13  97.51558
11 2022-08-13  98.36271
12 2023-08-13  98.85595
13 2024-08-13  99.14414
14 2025-08-13 100.00000
15 2026-08-13 100.00000
16 2027-08-13 100.00000
17 2028-08-13 100.00000
18 2029-08-13 100.00000
19 2030-08-13 100.00000
```

Obviously the coverage cannot exceed 100%. But when I build the following model:

```
make_model = function(df) {
  df$cap <- 100
  m <- prophet(growth = 'logistic')
  m <- add_regressor(m, name = 'Expln')
  m <- fit.prophet(m, df)
  return(m)
}

make_frcst = function(m, df) {
  future <- make_future_dataframe(m, 10, freq = 'year', include_history = TRUE)
  future$Expln <- df$Expln
  future$cap <- 100
  fcst <- predict(m, future)
  return(fcst)
}

> model = make_model(data)
Disabling weekly seasonality. Run prophet with weekly.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily.seasonality=TRUE to override this.
n.changepoints greater than number of observations. Using 6
> frcst = make_frcst(model, pred_data)
```

And plot the results, it gives this:

```
> plot(model, frcst)
>
```

[image: Forecats]

Why did the forecast exceed the 100 mark although I made the `cap` to be 100? The regressor also stops at 100. Can someone help me fix it?

Edit:

This is the `dput()` of the data I used:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(ds = structure(c(15565, 15930, 16295, 16660, 17026, 
17391, 17756, 18121, 18487), class = "Date"), y = c(59, 59, 59, 
65, 65, 67, 79, 82, 97.8), Expln = c(1, 21.79, 59.1, 71, 79.26572496, 
85.57208641, 89.87104819, 92.98642948, 95.98289404)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

> dput(pred_data)
structure(list(ds = structure(c(15565, 15930, 16295, 16660, 17026, 
17391, 17756, 18121, 18487, 18852, 19217, 19582, 19948, 20313, 
20678, 21043, 21409, 21774, 22139), class = "Date"), Expln = c(1, 
21.79, 59.1, 71, 79.26572496, 85.57208641, 89.87104819, 92.98642948, 
95.98289404, 97.51557771, 98.36271286, 98.85595395, 99.14414047, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: This is not the right the model based on the data you have.  Your dependent variable (the response) is a percentage (fraction), so you need to control the range of the model output. Generally, one way to do this is to use a Beta regression model, or to model the raw numbers directly. I don't know what options you have in `prophet`. Do you have the raw counts or raw numbers (rather than the calculated percentages)?

Comment: @MauritsEvers I don't have the raw numbers, only the percentage, and the prophet package only has `linear`, `logistic` or `flat` for `growth`. I thought `logistic` would be suitable since the data has an S-shape, it stops at 100.

Comment: The logistic trend component simply accounts for an asymptotic maximum (see [saturating growth](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html)). It's not bounded to the interval [0, 1].

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks, I checked the Beta regression but I couldn't any straightforward R example for time series data. I don't know if you know of any references.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure you can model these percentages directly in `prophet`. I think there are more questions though: Why do you want to run a time series model in the first place? Are you worried about seasonalities? Auto-regressive features? Why not fit a simple Beta regression model with the datestamp being encoded as a simply index? So something like `y ~ date_index + Expln` where `date_index` is just a running integer 0, 1, 2 etc based on `date_index = data$ds - min(data$ds)` (or something similar).

Comment: @MauritsEvers I modeled the data as time series because they are time series, and `prophet`was built specifically for that. But I will give your idea a try after reading a bit about Beta regression.

Comment: `prophet` is a tool that's particularly useful for modelling auto-regressive & seasonal features in data. These features often occur in time series data. `prophet` is a not the modelling tool for *all* time series data. In your case, a simple (Beta) regression model seems to be a lot more suitable. But this is more of a statistical modelling question than a coding question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On revisiting this post, here is what I would do:

- Use `rstanarm` to fit a Beta regression model of the form `y ~ year + Expln` to the data
- To forecast, we need values for `year` as well as `Expln`. While choosing future values for `year` is easy, you need to think harder about future values for `Expln`. This would also be necessary when you do forecasting in `prophet` with external regressors. In this example and for demonstration purposes, I simply duplicate the same set of `Expln` values from the past 9 years.

Let's start by loading necessary libraries

```r
library(rstanarm)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidybayes)
```

We then create a new `year` column, since your data seems to be yearly data. We also convert percentages to fractions [0, 1].

```r
data <- data %>% mutate(year = year(as.Date(ds)), y = y / 100)
```

We can then fit a Beta regression model in `rstanarm` (note that this requires you to install package `betareg`).

```r
fit <- stan_betareg(y ~ year + Expln, data = data)
```

We can now forecast; as mentioned in the beginning we simply forecast 9 years into the future, and copy `Expln` values from the previous 9 years. We then show posterior draws from the *expectation* of the posterior predictive.

```r
data %>%
    mutate(year = map(year, `+`, c(0, 10))) %>%
    unnest(year) %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    add_epred_draws(fit) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = y)) + 
    stat_lineribbon(aes(y = .epred), alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_point(data = data) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys") + 
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

A couple of observations:

- You can see how forecasts never exceed 100%.
- The kink in the (95% uncertainty band of the) forecasts in 2022 originates from the `Expln` value which has been copied from the 2012 value. This is (probably obviously) wrong.

As would have been the case with forecasting in `prophet` in the presence of external regressors, a two stage forecasting process is probably required:

1. Forecast `Expln` values based on domain-level knowledge or an independent forecasting model `Expln ~ year`.
2. Generate `Expln` for future years, then use those values and future `year` values to forecast `y` using this Beta regression model.

Comment: I didn't obtain the position for which his assignment was required, although I used the beta regression you suggested in the comments, but thank you.